# Java synchronized queue thread on producer and consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, queue, producer-consumer

Java producer-consumer program using thread & synchronized queue, the program is separated into 3 classes but it couldn't be run.

Queue.java:

```
public class Queue {
    static final int MAXQUEUE = 3;
    int[] queue = new int[MAXQUEUE];
    int front, rear;
    public Queue(){ front = 0; rear = 0; }
    public boolean isEmpty(){ return (front==rear); }

    public boolean isFull(){
        int index = rear+1 < MAXQUEUE ? rear+1 : 0;
        return (index == front);
    }

    public void enqueue(int value) {
        queue[rear] = value;
        rear = rear+1 < MAXQUEUE ? rear+1 : 0; 
    }

    public int dequeue(){
        int data = queue[front];
        front = front+1 < MAXQUEUE ? rear+1 : 0;
        return data;
    }
}
```

SynchronizedQueue.java:

```
import java.util.Queue;

public class SynchronizedQueue {
    Queue queue;
    public SynchronizedQueue() {queue = new Queue(); }
    public synchronized void enqueue(int value) {
        try {
            while (queue.isFull()) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Queue is full, please wait....");
                wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        ((SynchronizedQueue) queue).enqueue(value);
        notify();
    }
    public synchronized int dequeue() {
        try {
            while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Queue is empty, please wait....");
                wait();
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
        int data = ((SynchronizedQueue) queue).dequeue();
        notify();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Main program Ch10_3.java:

```
class Producer extends Thread {
    public int count = 0;
    public void run() {
        int value;
        while ( Ch10_3.isRunning ) {
            value = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            Ch10_3.squeue.enqueue(value);
            System.out.print(">" + value + "]");
            count++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*100));
            }
            catch( InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + Thread.currentThread() + "Producer thread end.");
    }
}

class Consumer extends Thread {
    public int count = 0;
    public void run() {
        int data;
        while (Ch10_3.isRunning) {
            data = Ch10_3.squeue.dequeue();
            System.out.println("[" + data + ">");
            count++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*100));
            }
            catch( InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + Thread.currentThread() + "Consumer thread end.");
    }
}

public class Ch10_3 {
    static final int MAXITEMS = 10;
    static SynchonizedQueue squeue = new SynchronizedQueue();
    static boolean isRunning = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Producer producer = new Producer();
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();

        producer.start();   consumer.start();
        while (true)
            if (producer.count >= MAXITEMS && producer.count == consumer.count)
            {   isRunning = false;  break; }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: at Ch10_3.main(Ch10_3.java:41)

Comment: And which line of code is line 41 of Ch10_3.java?

Comment: `static SynchonizedQueue squeue = new SynchronizedQueue();`

Comment: you misspell `SynchonizedQueue` write  `SynchronizedQueue`.

Comment: Correct it. XD, and here is new question: 
At SynchronizedQueue.java: 
`public SynchronizedQueue() {queue = new **Queue**(); }`
`while (queue.**isFull()**) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `catch` blocks from `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods form class `SynchronizedQueue` you are trying to cast the `queue` member attribute which is of type `Queue`, to `SynchronizedQueue`.

In `SynchronizedQueue.enqueue()` we have:

```
((SynchronizedQueue) queue).enqueue(value);
```

Since there is no relation between `Queue` and `SynchronizedQueue` the compiler gives a compilation error. You should remove the cast.

But the best solution is to just use a java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue implementation available in JAVA SDK, which will handle all the synchronisation part for you.

Comment: Could include new statement `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` help?  Error message "cannot instantiate type Queue" for this statement `public SynchronizedQueue() {queue = new Queue(); }` and "this method isFull() is undefined for type Queue"  for `while (queue.isFull()) {`

Comment: It will not help, and in general, you should not suppress any warnings, unless you know exactly what you are doing, and you do not want to bother by them during compilation. Did you update the code comparing to what you have initially posted, because the error message is very strange?

Comment: Oh yes, removed suppress statement and got error message: _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: Cannot instantiate the type Queue The method isFull() is undefined for the type Queue at SynchronizedQueue.<init>(SynchronizedQueue.java:5) at Ch10_3.<clinit>(Ch10_3.java:38)_